# error: createNetworkInterface is not a function on React Native and Apollo Client

Tags: android, react-native, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've been trying to use apollo client on my react-native project so that I can connect to a fully developed apollo graphql server. However I'm getting an error that suggests that `createNetworkInterface` is not the correct way to do it. How should I initialize the apollo client? [Error from the debugging mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk80p.jpg)

The code that I used to initialize the apollo client is:

```
// Initialize the Apollo Client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/ciwce5xw82kh7017179gwzn7q',
  }),
})
```

I have really tried my best to look for solutions on how to implement this, but most tutorials/documentations are for react for web and none is for react-native. Sorry about my bad English :(

Comment: What version of Apollo client are you using?

Comment: "react-apollo": "^2.0.4" . Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue some time back. Unfortunately I couldn't find any other solution other than to downgrade my react-apollo and react-native dependencies as below:

```
yarn add react-apollo@1.0.0
```

and also install an older version of react-native:

```
react-native init appName --version react-native@0.45.0
```

You could also refer to some thread on this issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/108) and [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2458).